# Ruby on Rails Oracle encoding

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, oracle, encoding, utf-8

I cannot seem to get the encoding right on my Oracle RoR combi. The information in the Oracle database seems to be encoded correctly. When looking up an attribute via SQL in need of special encoding I get eg 'Straße' which is what I expect. When requesting that same attribute from my RoR application I get 'Stra?e' which obviously is incorrect.

- The NLS_LANG in ENV on the Oracle server is = `AMERICAN_AMERICA.AL32UTF8`
- The encoding in the database.yml in my RoR app = `utf8`
- The NLS_NCHAR_CHARACTERSET of the Oracle dbase = `AL16UTF16`

I tried a couple of different things by changing the parameters above but nothing worked.

Anybody have a good idea?

Comment: what driver are you using? Oracle-enhanced?

Comment: Mark, yes I am. I just found out that by adding NLS_LANG="AMERICAN_AMERICA.UTF8" to the environment of my dev machine the problem was solved there. On my production machine I tried the same but no luck. I also added AddDefaultCharset UTF-8 to htaccess but that didn;t solve it either. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Is the version of Ruby different in dev and production?

Comment: Both ruby 1.8.7 (different patches)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Things that worked was to downgrade my oracle enhance gem

Answer (score 7):

Add `ENV['NLS_LANG'] ||= 'AMERICAN_AMERICA.UTF8'` to `...\config\boot.rb` and it will work on all environments.

Answer (score 4):

None of the solutions I could find on the web worked, but after reading the source of the ruby-oci8 gem, putting:

`ENV['NLS_LANG'] = 'AMERICAN_AMERICA.AL32UTF8'
DEFAULT_OCI8_ENCODING = 'utf-8'`

in `config\boot.rb` worked for me.

Answer (score 1):

Just run before load app

```
OCI8.encoding=Encoding.default_internal
```

You can do too on put on first line on config/boot.rb

```
ENV['NLS_LANG'] = 'AMERICAN_AMERICA.UTF8'
```

This ensure that yours string will be in utf8 format when goes to database

Comment: It would be helpful if you could explain why this solves OP's original question. Code only answers are generally not super helpful for future users and OP if they don't understand what you've done. Please add some context to your answer.